# XML parsing java using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jaxb

I am looking for some source code that, creates Java Classes using, JAXB. I have the Schemas, and the XML file.
Or any tutorial on JAXB if possible.
thx

Answer (score 3):

Um, http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/.

Answer (score 2):

Check out my blog for JAXB examples:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-jaxb.html

Answer (score 0):

1. The ICEfaces Tutorial [link](http://facestutorials.icefaces.org/tutorial/JAXB-Tree-tutorial.html)
2. The Roseindia Tutorial [link](http://www.roseindia.net/jaxb/r/jaxb.shtml)

Both have sample code and are short and simple, to get you started.